# Mac Word new line character

Tags: javascript, macos, ms-word

In my Office JS API, I'm returning a string with embedded strings from an API call.

On Mac Word, the function doesn't seem to work. The text continues to look like this:

> and the stars.\n\nOne day, the village was hit by a devastating storm
> that destroyed several houses and crops. The villagers were left in
> despair,

I've tried all forms of replacing the "\n" with other characters but it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone found a solution to this?

```
 let result = response.replaceAll("\n\n", "\r\n");
```

I've tried replacing with

```
String.fromCharCode(10) and
String.fromCharCode(13)
```

I've tried the "\n" and "\r"

Anyone seen a solution to this?

Comment: `response.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\n")`

Comment: The issue isn't finding all of the "\n". The replaceAll is doing that. The issue is the second half "the \n" isn't what Mac Word sees as a new line. That's what I need help with.

Comment: My replace will take any \n except if you have \\n in the text. Perhaps you need to JSON.parse the string or some other parsing

Comment: The issue is not in finding. The issue is in the replace. Microsoft word doesn’t see \n as a new line character. I need help discovering what to put there in the replace side not in the find side.

Comment: How are you inserting the replacement text into the document? IMO you have to do something like rng.insertText(result,"Replace"), where rng is a Word.Range object. You may also need a context.sync(). In that case, where you have a "\n" (whether that actually represents a unicode 10 character or the two-character string representation of it), replacing it by String.fromCharCode(13) is what you need to get full Word paragraph marks in there. (Be aware that in Word, it's arguably "more correct" to insert new paragraphs using insertParagraph then put the appropriate pieces of text in each one).

Comment: BTW, just in case you are experiencing different results on Win, Mac and web versions, the tests I just did were on Mac Word 16.74 (23061100) on ARM.